# Deciding which collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have an abstract class which is extended by large number of other POJOs, I need all these main POJOs to be stored in a dedicated collection.

My repository looks like this:

```
interface TimesliceRepository extends MongoRepository<AbstractTimeslice, String>
```

How can I make it so that objects are directed to the appropriate collection? Eg: AATimeslice, BBTimeslice, etc...

Or do I have to have a repository for every POJO?
Also, would read queries work? How would I be able to query for BBTimeslice only?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I came to the conclusion that for my uses cases its better to use MongoTemplate and not MongoRepository.